# Modular Arithmetic: Multiplicative inverse

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I want to solve this question using mod arithmetic:

7/3 mod 8.

Somebody told me to do it using multiplicative inverse:

7 (Multiplicative inverse of 3) mod 8

I can't find any example related to the above method.
Somebody please guide me.

Zulfi.

Comment: Note that $3\times 3 =9\equiv 1 \pmod 8$.

Comment: Please read this [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) to begin with and share your thoughts and efforts in the question

Comment: @lulu: Where is 7?

Comment: I didn't solve the entire problem for you.  I just showed you how to find a multiplicative inverse for $3\pmod 8$.

Comment: So will the above question become: 7 * 9 mod 8, some body please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using multiplicative inverse would work, but also note that $7\equiv15\pmod 8$ — now can you solve your question using modular arithmetic?

Comment: First I want to solve the above one, then I would try this one. I can't understand the solution for my question. Why you put the "mod 8" in brackets?

Comment: $3$ is its own inverse mod $8$, so $7/3\equiv 7\times3\pmod8; $ that gives the same answer as mine.    Putting mod $8$ in parentheses is standard mathematical notation

Comment: It would become "21 mod 8", that would be 5, is this correct, sorry your answer was 1.

Comment: $5$ is correct; my answer was also $15/3=5$

Comment: I have two more questions: 9/6 mod 11, that would be 9 * (MI of 6) mod 11; 9 * 6 mod 11; 54 mod 11 i.e. 9 or it should be 3/2 mod 11, that would be 3 * (MI of 2) mod 11; 6 mod 11= 6, which answer is correct? Should I have to simplify first? Somebody please guide me.

Comment: probably answered elsewhere on this site, but $9/6\equiv 9\times6^{-1}\equiv 9\times 2=18\equiv7\pmod{11}$ and also $9/6\equiv3/2\equiv3\times6=18\equiv7\pmod{11}$